# Cisco 4948 can ping out, but no connections inboud

Tags: cisco-ios

n00b question here I suspect...
I received a used Cisco 4948 (not an 'E' or 'F') Switch that I am trying to get configured for SSH Management access.  I can ping out from the switch to nodes that are local to the same subnet that I have 'Vlan1' configured for, but not able to ping the switch.  I have another dumb hub connected to gig1/1, and I can see 802.1d packets coming from the switch, so I am assuming my issue is a config issue. No pings, and SSH just times out on connect tries.

Vlan1 is configured as this:

```
switch1>sh int vlan1
Vlan1 is up, line protocol is up
  Hardware is Ethernet SVI, address is 001e.f7ad.66bf (bia 001e.f7ad.66bf)
  Internet address is 10.147.123.2/24
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 1000000 Kbit, DLY 10 usec,
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
  Last input 00:00:00, output never, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 0
  Queueing strategy: fifo
  Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
  5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  L3 in Switched: ucast: 239 pkt, 19252 bytes - mcast: 0 pkt, 0 bytes
  L3 out Switched: ucast: 0 pkt, 0 bytes - mcast: 0 pkt, 0 bytes
     409 packets input, 62554 bytes, 0 no buffer
     Received 170 broadcasts (22 IP multicast)
     0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     96 packets output, 6558 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 interface resets
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
```

And Gig1/1 like this:

```
switch1> sh int gig1/1
GigabitEthernet1/1 is up, line protocol is up (connected)
  Hardware is Gigabit Ethernet Port, address is 001e.f7ad.6680 (bia 001e.f7ad.6)
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 1000000 Kbit, DLY 10 usec,
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
  Keepalive set (10 sec)
  Full-duplex, 1000Mb/s, link type is auto, media type is 10/100/1000-TX
  input flow-control is on, output flow-control is off
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
  Last input never, output never, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  Input queue: 0/2000/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 0
  Queueing strategy: fifo
  Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
  5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
     574140 packets input, 46267278 bytes, 0 no buffer
     Received 573846 broadcasts (70850 multicast)
     0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     0 input packets with dribble condition detected
     141011 packets output, 10520046 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 0 interface resets
     0 babbles, 0 late collision, 0 deferred
     0 lost carrier, 0 no carrier
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
switch1>sh ip int gig1/1
GigabitEthernet1/1 is up, line protocol is up
  Inbound  access list is 1
  Outgoing access list is 1
switch1>sh access-lists 1
Standard IP access list 1
    10 permit any (1525 matches)
```

I'm obviously missing something fundamental, but all the how-to's I can find tell you to run the commands like I did, and everything just starts working.

My `sh term` command has these lines:

```
Allowed input transports are none.
Allowed output transports are telnet ssh.
```

...which to me look suspect for getting ssh working.

Thanks for you help :)

**Edit:** Full config:

```
switch1#sh run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 2677 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service pad
service timestamps debug uptime
service timestamps log uptime
no service password-encryption
service compress-config
!
hostname switch1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
enable password {password}
!
username admin password 0 {password}
no aaa new-model
clock timezone CDT -6
ip subnet-zero
ip domain-name home.gan
ip name-server 10.1.1.20
!
ip ssh time-out 90
!
!
!
no file verify auto
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
power redundancy-mode redundant
!
!
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
 switchport mode access
 ip access-group 1 in
 ip access-group 1 out
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/2
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/3
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/4
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/5
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/6
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/7
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/8
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/9
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/10
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/11
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/12
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/13
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/14
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/15
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/16
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/17
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/18
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/19
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/20
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/21
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/22
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/23
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/25
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/26
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/27
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/28
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/29
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/30
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/31
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/32
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/33
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/34
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/35
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/36
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/37
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/38
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/39
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/40
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/41
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/42
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/43
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/44
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/45
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/46
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/47
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/48
!
interface Vlan1
 ip address 10.1.2.2 255.255.255.0
!
ip default-gateway 10.1.2.1
ip http server
!
!
!
ip access-list standard SSH-ACCESS
 permit 10.1.2.0 0.0.0.255
 permit 10.1.5.0 0.0.0.255
 permit 10.1.9.0 0.0.0.255
 permit 10.1.12.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 1 permit any
access-list 102 permit icmp any any echo-reply
!
!
!
line con 0
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 access-class SSH-ACCESS in
 exec-timeout 2880 0
 password {password}
 logging synchronous
 login
 length 0
 transport input ssh
line vty 5 15
 password {password}
 login
!
!
end
```

SSH keys have already been generated.

**Edit2**

```
switch1#sh spanning-tree vlan 1

VLAN0001
  Spanning tree enabled protocol ieee
  Root ID    Priority    32769
             Address     001e.f7ad.6680
             This bridge is the root
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    32769  (priority 32768 sys-id-ext 1)
             Address     001e.f7ad.6680
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
             Aging Time 300

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Gi1/1            Desg FWD 4         128.1    P2p
```

Comment: You need to, at least, edit your question to include the full (sanitized) switch configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't provide a full configuration, it's impossible to say for sure what the problem is. But from the information you did provide, you do need to add this command:

```
transport input ssh
```

You will also need to generate keys for ssh authentication, if you haven't already done so.

```
ip domain-name foo.com
crypto ket generate rsa 4096
```

Comment: Add 'transport input ssh' to what?  It's there in the 'line vty 0 4' section...does it need to be someplace else??

Comment: That wasn't in your original post.  Just to be clear:  you can ping your default gateway from the switch, but you cannot ping the switch from the default gateway?

Comment: That is correct Ron.

Comment: What is your default gateway?    Can you post the output of "show spanning-tree vlan 1"?

Comment: Also, try removing access-list 1 from the gi 1/1 interface (both in and out).  ACLs should be put on the VLAN interface.

Comment: For my edification, what does show spanning-tree command tell you?  I don't have any STP in my network, so curious about what this tells you :)

Comment: @JohnAllen "_I don't have any STP in my network, so curious about what this tells you_" Yes, you do because you have not disabled STP. It is on for every VLAN by default. Your own output confirms it is enabled: `Spanning tree enabled protocol ieee`

Comment: The spanning-tree shows that your port is forwarding.  Your configuration appears correct except for the ACL, so if you've removed that and it still doesn't work, I'm suspicious of your gateway device.  What is that?

Comment: @RonTrunk  Removed ACLs, still no luck from local subnet. Added static routes to other subnets, can http, ssh & ping fine from them....just not the locally attached subnet?!?  I can work around that, but would be good to understand why the locally attached subnet doesn't work, and everything else does.  Thanks :)

Comment: Can you run a sniffer on that port?  There is no "normal" reason why it shouldn't.  Now we're looking for oddball reasons.

Comment: Ping the switch from the default gateway, then run "show arp" on the switch.  Post that to your question.

Comment: Could it be a duplicate ip address?